# Create a hierarchical object from a flat list parent-child

Tags: javascript, json, parent-child

I am trying to understand the best approach in JS to create an object to pass to a tree view component. I'm struggling to understand where to begin with regards to the approach. I have tried doing various things such as splitting the parent child relationship number into an array and then iterating over them, pushing them into a new object, but I still don't know how to keep the relationships. Do i need recursion?

Given the following list of parent child relationships, and associated depth level

```
1 , depth 1
1.1, depth 2
1.1.1, depth 3
1.1.2, depth 3
1.2.1, depth 3
1.2.2, depth 3
1.2.3, depth 3
1.2.3.4, depth 4
```

and the output tree below

```
1
-1
--1
--2
-2
--1
---1
...
```

Resulting object should looking like

```
[
  {
    "1": {
      "depth": "1",
      "child": {
        "1.1": {
          "depth": "2",
          "child": {
            "1.1.1": {
              "depth": "3",
              "child": null
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "level": "2",
      "depth": "1",
      "child": {
        "2.1": {
          "depth": "2",
          "child": {
            "2.1.1": {
              "depth": "3",
              "child": null
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

What would be the best approach in JS to iterate through the list and generate a tree digram, or atleast the object that a tree diagram component could consume?

Comment: what is output? html or a data structure? have you tried anything?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Picking up on Andreas' point, JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. You probably just want to create nested objects, nothing whatsoever to do with JSON.

Comment: The "level" part of your list seems superfluous, it's implicit in the `1.2.3` and such...? What does that "list of parent child relationships" **really** look like? (E.g., the data structure that's the input to what you want to do.)

Comment: You could sort your data source by depth. Then iterate the source creating each level. If the depth changes from the previous iteration step down a level.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder added what the object should look like. "level" should read "depth".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having an array of sorted items and a level information, you could use an helper array fro keeping track of the last inserted items at a givel level and use this storage to get nested items to the right place.

**This approach does not rely on the given `title`, only on the order of the items and `level`.**

```js
var data = [{ title: '1', level: 1 }, { title: '1.1', level: 2 }, { title: '1.1.1', level: 3 }, { title: '1.1.2', level: 3 }, { title: '1.2.1', level: 3 }, { title: '1.2.2', level: 3 }, { title: '1.2.3', level: 3 }, { title: '1.2.3.4', level: 4 }],
    result = [],
    levels = [result];

data.forEach(({ title, level }) =>
    levels[level - 1].push({ title, children: levels[level] = [] })
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The wanted one. No `level` used.

```js
var data = [{ title: '1', level: 1 }, { title: '1.1', level: 2 }, { title: '1.1.1', level: 3 }, { title: '1.1.2', level: 3 }, { title: '1.2.1', level: 3 }, { title: '1.2.2', level: 3 }, { title: '1.2.3', level: 3 }, { title: '1.2.3.4', level: 4 }],
    result = {};

data.forEach(({ title, level }) =>
    title
        .split('.')
        .reduce((o, _, i, values) => {
            var key = values.slice(0, i + 1).join('.');
            o.child = o.child || {};
            return o.child[key] = o.child[key] || { depth: i + 1 };
        }, { child: result })
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```